# Guardar todos os tipos de variáveis em um vetor/array?

Tags: c#, .net, lista, objetos

Como posso armazenar dentro de um vetor valores e variáveis de todo os tipos? Ex:

```
vetor1.Add("valor em string");
vetor1.Add(100);
vetor1.Add(100.10);
vetor1.Add(-100);
```

Não tenho ideia de como posso fazer isso.

Comment: Tem certeza que é isso que você quer? Recuperar esses dados depois pode ser trabalhoso

Comment: Sim, conforme a resposta abaixo do Maniero, descobri que para recuperar os dados do `object` é só dar um `cast`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso não parece um *array* e sim uma lista. O tipo geral para todos os tipos é o `object`, então é só usá-lo.

```
var vetor = new List<object>() { "string", 100, 100.10, -100 };
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/Syntax.cs).